# Understanding the try/catch with Promises. Have not gone over the concept of async/await just yet

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, try-catch

Before I start tackling async/await I was wondering if it possible to still use the try/catch syntax like this with/inside Promises. Or am I 'mixing' two concepts now? Also, I wonder if this is best practice in regarding handling errors?

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const checkType = (num1, num2) => {
  if (typeof num1 !== 'number' || typeof num2 !== 'number') {
    throw new Error('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
};

const add = (number1, number2) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      checkType(number1, number2);
      timeout(1000).then(() => resolve(number1 + number2));
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  })
};


add(5,'foo').then((result)=> console.log(result)).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Comment: `checkType()` is synchronous code so you can use `try/catch` around calls to it just like you always did, even if it's inside a promise executor function.  For a real world problem, there may be simpler ways to code than you've shown so it's more about using the tools of the language in the ways they are best suited to end up with the cleanest code and some of those choices are opinion too.

Comment: Personal opinion: For something like `checkType()`, I would normally just have it return a boolean and not use exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking about that too. Then I will at least get rid of the try/catch inside the Promise function, which will make it more readable. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

You can also normally use `try/catch` outside `async/await` concept if your synchronous function is throwing an exception.